# Eventbrite API date range parameter for organizer_list_events

Tags: api, date, eventbrite, organizer

I need a way to search via the eventbrite api past events, by organizer, that are private, but I also need to be able to limit the date range. I have not found a viable solution for this search. I assume the organizer_list_events api would be the preferred method, but the request paramaters don't seem to allow for the date range, and I am getting FAR too many returns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some similar issues I posted a question to get a response about parsing the timezone, here's the code I'm using to get the dates though and exclude any events before today (unfortunately like you said I'm still getting everything sent to me and paring things out client side)

Note this is an AngularJS control but the code is just using the EventBrite javascript API.

function EventCtrl($http, $scope)
{
    $scope.events=[];
    $scope.noEventsDisplay = "Loading events...";

```
Eventbrite({'app_key': "EVC36F6EQZZ4M5DL6S"}, function(eb){

    // define a few parameters to pass to the API
    // Options are listed here: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/organizers/organizer_list_events/
    //3877641809
    var options = {
        'id'    : "3588304527",

    };

    // provide a callback to display the response data:
    eb.organizer_list_events( options, function( response ){
        validEvents = [];

        var now = new Date().getTime();
        for(var i = 0; i<response.events.length; i++)
        {
            var sd = response.events[i].event.start_date;
            var ed = response.events[i].event.end_date;

            var parsedSD = sd.split(/[:-\s]/);
            var parsedED = ed.split(/[:-\s]/);

            var startDate = new Date(parsedSD[0], parsedSD[1]-1, parsedSD[2], parsedSD[3], parsedSD[4], parsedSD[5]);
            var endDate = new Date(parsedED[0], parsedED[1]-1, parsedED[2], parsedED[3], parsedED[4], parsedED[5]);

            if(endDate.getTime()<now)
                continue;

            response.events[i].event.formattedDate = date.toDateString();
            validEvents.push(response.events[i])
        }
        if(validEvents.length == 0)
        {
            $scope.$apply(function(scope){scope.noEventsDisplay = "No upcoming events to display, please check back soon.";});
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.$apply(function(scope){scope.noEventsDisplay = "";});
        }
        $scope.$apply(function(scope){scope.events = validEvents;});

        //$('.event_list').html(eb.utils.eventList( response, eb.utils.eventListRow ));
    });
});
```

}